# Comparing dates within a text colum, formated as JSON, in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, text, sqldatatypes, date-comparison

I've got a bizarre setup I am working with where, I have a table with multiple columns. One of the columns, I'll call it "weird-column" has data type of text **but** the information that is stored *within* that column appears to be listed as JSON.

"Why wasn't this column data type set as JSON or JSONB?" No idea - this is a DB that I was given to work with.

Example:

```
{
  "id": "numbers-and-letters-go-here":[
    {
      "Code": "thing"
    }
  ],
  "issuedt": "03/18/1989",
  "expirationdate": "03/18/3089",
  "firstname": "Funky",
  "middlename": "Cold",
  "lastname": "Medina"
}
```

Now, I need to compare dates stored *within* weird-column, to see if any expriationdate expire *before* issuedt. I need to do this for **every entry** in weird-column and see output for the entries for each record which expired before it was even issued.

My initial plan was to use something like

```
select * from table_1
where issuedt < expriationdate
```

but since all of this is data stored *within* weird-column, that wouldn't work. Is there a way to specify this? Something like

```
select * from table_1
where weird-column.issuedt < weird-column.expriationdate
```

I don't have the knowledge to describe what it is that I need to do, but have a vague understanding of what I need done. Any suggestions at all would be extremley helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "every entry"? Can a record have a JSON that contains multiple entries or can we assume that each record has a JSON that is structured like the example you gave?

Answer (score 1):

If your `weird-column` is a well formed json then you can simply cast it to jsonb

e.g

```sql
select '{"name":"xyz", "age" : 34}'::jsonb
```

once converted to json, you can use various operators including the `->` operator to select a particular field in the json and further operate on it

```sql
select (('{"name":"xyz", "age" : 34}'::jsonb) -> 'age')::integer
```

do check out this page for more details https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Comment: thank you kindly for the response. If I "cast" this to jsonb, will it create a new column in the database?

I only  have read access to this database. The central task I am trying to do is just query information that already exists - I'm not permitted to modify anything that exists within it for some complex legal reasons.

Comment: no, it will not create a new column, it's a on the fly operation.

Comment: Sharang, thank you kindly for the response. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=48d46b7347ce4452651745df4b651dab)
your text column is ill formed for converting it to jsonb/json.

```
"id": "numbers-and-letters-go-here":[
    {
      "Code": "thing"
    }
  ]
```

jsonb/json is more like `"key":"value"`, it cannot  `"key":"value": "value1"`.
I changed it to

```
  "id": "numbers-and-letters-go-here",
  "id1": [
    {
      "Code": "thing"
    }
  ]
```

final code for compare issuedt with expirationdate

```
SELECT
    to_date((weird::jsonb)->>'issuedt','MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM
    t1
where to_date((weird::jsonb)->>'issuedt','MM/DD/YYYY')
    <  to_date((weird::jsonb)->>'expirationdate','MM/DD/YYYY') ;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your thorough response. Honestly, there are many things I would wish to do differently in how this data is presented. Unforchantly, I do not make those decisions. I've been given the ability to read and query information of the existing database, but do not have any sort of authority to change anything within it. Do you know if anything close to what you are suggesting could feasibly work without changing how the text column is formed? I completely agree with what you are saying, I am simply in a spot where I cannot do anything to change how it is formatted.

Comment: try text string manipulation to make it formatted look like json.

Comment: Mark, thank you kindly for the information. I will make sure to look into this.